# HttpWebRequest dosent get response

Tags: c#, .net, web, httpwebrequest

When i try to load "https://web.com/forum" i dont get response, this url dosent need login to load. With the browser i only have to copy the url and it works fine without previous session.

When i try to load other url like "https://web.com" it works but "https://web.com/forum" dosent work. why?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://web.com/forum");
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            req.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            req.Referer = "https://web.com/forum";
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Host = "web.com";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0";
            req.Proxy = null;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
```

What's the problem here?.

I have tried also to remove referer, contentype, useragent... and other headers without success.

Thanks.

Comment: I get a 404 at `/forum`. You might try setting the `AllowAutoRedirect` property on `HttpWebRequest` if you really want the 404 page. You might also consider using `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: Sorry but it is not the real url, i prefer to let it private. I also tasted with AllowAutoRedirect. I can verify that the url redirects so i use it without success. Thank you and regards.

Comment: Is the certificate of that https connection trusted? What does *don't get response* mean? If you hookup [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) what do you see?